# Drop rows with specific string value pandas

Tags: string, pandas, contains

I have some a df with bridge data where in certain columns the string "(R)" is in. I want to remove those rows if "Blabla (R)" or "hello (R)" is the value. (so something with str.contains)

[image]

As in the picture, i want to drop row 9. (and many more)

Why is this error given and how to fix this?

Comment: `df.drop` is a method (function), you can't index it with `[ ]`. Maybe `df.drop(df.str.contains(...))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to remove any rows where the `road` field in the `df` dataframe equals `(S)`, then you can use the following code. This will remove these rows within the same dataframe `(df)`

```
df.drop(index=df[df['road'] == '(R)'].index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Doesn't work, this only deletes rows which are exactly (R), but i want to delete all the rows if they even consist "blabla (R)".

Comment: OK, I misunderstood. I thought you wanted exactly that. Try this instead.

`df.drop(index=df[df['road'].str.contains('(R)')].index, inplace=True)`

Comment: it worked! I only had to type it like contains.('\(R\)) because of the parenthesis in the string

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the question, str.contains is a useful tool for a wildcard search.

`df.drop(df[df['name'].str.contains('R')].index.tolist())`

`.index` returns a Int64Index that is not iterable so `.tolist()` converts this to a list and is finally ready for `df.drop([])`.